# Parameterized queries qraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I want to make parameterized requests from the Apollo client to the Apollo server.

On client:

```
const GET_VALUES = gql`
query Values($desc: String!) {      
    Values      
}    
`;
```

```
function ValueSelector({ pickValue, dirDesc }) { 
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_VALUES, {
variables: { dirDesc },
 });
}
```

On server (schema):

```
type Query {
Values(desc: String!): [String]
@cypher(
  statement: "MATCH (:Dir{description:$desc})-[:value]->(v) RETURN collect(v.TXTLG)"
 )  
}
```

Result:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Field "Values" argument "desc" of type "String!" is required, but it was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
[Network error]: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

Comment: `dirDesc` provided instead of `desc`

Comment: @xadm I changed aliases but the result is the same

Comment: GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const GET_VALUES = gql`
    query Values($desc: String!) {      
      Values(desc: $desc)  
    }    
  `;

function ValueSelector({ pickValue, dirDesc }) {   
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_VALUES, {
    variables: { desc:dirDesc},
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `desc` instead of `dirDesc` in variables param of useQuery. Try this:

```js
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_VALUES, {
variables: { desc: dirDesc },
 });
```

Comment: result is the same (

Comment: You should change you query to this ```const GET_VALUES = gql`
query Values($desc: String!) {      
    Values(desc: $desc)      
}``` @a1olegs

Answer (score 0):

Your query declaration on the client is missing the actual variable. It should be something like this

```
const GET_VALUES = gql`
    query Values($desc: String!) {      
         Values(dirDesc: $desc)      
    }    
`;
```

Then you can use useQuery passing dirDesc.